# Azure site recovery fabric registration not found

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-site-recovery

I am trying to create 1 VM azure site recovery configuration and using sample terraform code from https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/site_recovery_replicated_vm.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = ">= 2.49.0"
  features {
    
  }
}

Once deployment reached to site fabric configuration i am getting below error:

Error: Error checking for presence of existing site recovery fabric dplprimary-fabric (vault dlp01example-recovery-vault): siterecovery.ReplicationFabricsClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="NotFound" Message="Fabric with name dplprimary-fabric could not be located." Details=[{"activityId":"","clientRequestId":"","code":"FabricArmEntityMissing","message":"Fabric with name dplprimary-fabric could not be located.","possibleCauses":"The fabric might have been unregistered from the Microsoft Azure Site Recovery vault.","recommendedAction":"Retry the operation with a valid site."}]

  on main.tf line 218, in resource "azurerm_site_recovery_fabric" "primary":
 218: resource "azurerm_site_recovery_fabric" "primary" {
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been introduced with version 2.46 of the azurerm provider, and has been fixed by [pull request 11130](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/11130). Update your provider to a version >= 2.54 and everything should work